# Приедешь - сразу ко мне!

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить тип предложения:

> *Приедешь - сразу ко мне!*

Для моего языка такая конструкция не характерна. Если переведу, придется переводить как придаточное времени (*Как только/когда приедешь, ...*). Но из Ваших ответов поняла, что если нет подчинительного союза, это не придаточное. Неужели это два простых предложения, которые соединены тире?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Это БСП с временным отношением между предложениями**, вот примеры: Начнется отпуск ― съездим. Останетесь одни ― тогда и живите, как хотите.

(1) **Приедешь ― (2) сразу ко мне**! Аналог: Как только ты приедешь, сразу иди (зайди и т.д.) ко мне.

**Первое предложение** односоставное определенно-личное, производитель действия (ты) определяется из формы глагола (2-е лицо).

**Второе предложение** эллиптического характера, так как сказуемое подразумевается, но семантически точно не называется.